# Get a Map<Long, Long> from Ebean sql query

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to implement a function that should return a Map, the Long values is IDs of two different systems. I'm using Java Playframework 2.

Let's say I have 100 systems in my database. The query finds if there is a relation between to systems and the output in sql is this:

```
1254          1380 
1254          1389 
1258          1259 
1259          1258 
1380          1254
```

I think this is a Map, right?

Here is my function:

```
public static Map<Long, Long> show_all_system_relations_between_systems() {
    List <Infoobjectrelationtype> typeIdList = Infoobjectrelationtype.find.where().ilike("designation","is_a").findList();
    Long typeId = typeIdList.get(0).infoobjectrelationtype_id; 

    List <Infoobject> ioList = Infoobject.find.where().ilike("designation","SYSTEM").findList();
    Long systemId = ioList.get(0).infoobjectId;

    SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select distinct ir1.infoobject_id, ir2.infoobject_id from infoobjectrelation ir1, infoobjectrelation ir2 where ir1.related_infoobject_id = ir2.related_infoobject_id and ir1.related_infoobject_id !=" + systemId + " and ir1.infoobject_id != ir2.infoobject_id and ir1.infoobject_id in (select infoobject_id from infoobjectrelation where infoobjectrelationtype_id =" +typeId+ " and related_infoobject_id =" +systemId+ ") and ir2.infoobject_id in (select infoobject_id from infoobjectrelation where infoobjectrelationtype_id =" +typeId+ " and related_infoobject_id =" + systemId +") order by ir1.infoobject_id");
    Map<Long, Long> rows = query.findMap();

    return rows;
}
```

Error message:

*incompatible types [found: java.util.Map< capture#481 of ?, com.avaje.ebean.SqlRow> [required: java.util.Map< java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long >]*

How can I make this function work? Can I make a List of it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findMap()` method of `SqlQuery` does not return a `Map<Long,Long>`, it returns a `Map<?, SqlRow>`. See the [ebean API here](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html#findMap%28%29).

Try returning a `List<SqlRow>` instead, using `findList()`, and then use the methods contained in `SqlRow` to access the two `Long` values.

Here's [the API doc](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlRow.html) for `SqlRow`.